# Using Aiksaurus for NLP

Tags: nlp

What is the original source for the thesaurus data in [Aiksaurus](http://aiksaurus.sourceforge.net/)?

Is it possible to get data about antonyms for a word from Aiksaurus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used Aiksaurus, but it seems to based on the ['Moby Thesaurus List' by Grady Ward](http://www.gutenberg.org/etext/3202). It's even mentioned on the main project page.

Comment: and re: antonyms, the moby thesaurus doesn't list them, i don't think